# define new layers and refer file path in docker caffe

Tags: docker, caffe, pycaffe

New to both caffe and docker here. I just followed [this](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/playing-with-caffe-and-docker-to-build-deep-learning-models-99c9570ffc3d) post and ran a training example on MNIST data in docker caffe using jupyter notebook. Now say I want to use a customized loss function. I learned that if it's a classically installed caffe, the newly created .hpp file should be put into $CAFFE_PATH/include/caffe/layers/ and .cpp file should be put into $CAFFE_PATH/src/caffe/layers/
However in docker, how to find these directories? (or if there's such concept?)

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same. I added the .hpp file and .cpp file to the corresponding directories. And made sure to register the layer in the .cpp file. When I try to initiate my Net in jupyter, the kernel keeps dying, so I assume caffe might still not be recognizing the new layer. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the article it says

```
docker run -p 8887:8888 -v ~/Desktop/caffee/model2/notebooks:/model1/notebooks -v ~/Desktop/caffe/model2/data:/model1/data -d model2
```

So this will place the generated files in `~/Desktop/caffe/model2/data` on your system. If you want to explore the files insider the container. You will do

```
$ docker ps
```

This will show you the id of your container. Then get a bash inside it

```
$ docker exec -it <containerid> /bin/bash
```

Once inside you can got to the `/model1/data`

```
cd /model1/data
```

Or any folder for that matter and explore the files.